# Mongodb find maximum based on nested object key

Tags: mongodb

I have below schema where I need to identify the object which has highest rank.

```
{ "team" : {
    "member1" : [ {   "rank": 2, "goal": 50 } ], 
    "member2" : [ {   "rank": 5, "goal": 30 } ], 
    "member3" : [ {   "rank": 1, "goal": 80 } ] 
}}
```

$unwind will not work on the nested objects. Tried to convert this object as Array and tried to find the max of rank key. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to only find the maximum rank that exists: The idea is a two stage aggregation query using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to have common keys from which [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) on required attribute can be applied.

**Query:** [playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W387S_Jleku)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      teamsData: {
        $objectToArray: "$team"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      maxRank: {
        $max: "$teamsData.v.rank"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

To get the object details that has the maximum rank: Use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array projected from previous stage to help in sorting by rank [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) and then picking the the first item [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) at [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage.

**Query:** [playgorund link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oyKISakcwIu)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      team: {
        $objectToArray: "$team"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$team"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "team.v.rank": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      maxRankObj: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Sample O/P:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "maxRankObj": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "team": {
        "k": "member2",
        "v": [
          {
            "goal": 30,
            "rank": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```